# python - problems handling exception and continuing

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I am building or trying to build a python script which check's a list of ip addresses (ips.txt) for a specific program using the wmi python module.  However, no matter how I handle the exceptions on assets with no RPC service running the script stops running on an error.  I am using python 2.7.5

Can I catch and pass the error's to proceed?
Can I catch the error and print or return a note that the ip was not alive or rpc was not running?

Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

```
import wmi
list = open("ips.txt")

for line in list.readlines():
    asset = line.strip('\n')
    c = wmi.WMI(asset)
    try:
        for process in c.Win32_Process (name="SbClientManager.exe"):
            print asset, process.ProcessId, process.Name
    except Exception:
        pass
```

I have tried handling the exceptions in multiple way's to continue parsing my list, but the script continues to error out with the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\check_service.py", line 12, in <module>
    c = wmi.WMI(asset)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1290, in connect
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)>
```

Ultimately, I am just trying to continue the script and catch the error.  Maybe a note stating that IP was not responsive would be helpful.  Here are the exceptions samples that I have tried:

```
except Exception:
    sys.exc_clear()

except:
    pass

except wmi.x_wmi, x:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traceback you pasted says that the error is in the `c = wmi.WMI(asset)` line. You need to put that line inside the `try` block.

Like so:

```
import wmi
list = open("ips.txt")
bad_assets = []

for line in list.readlines():
    asset = line.strip('\n')
    try:
        c = wmi.WMI(asset)
        for process in c.Win32_Process (name="SbClientManager.exe"):
            print asset, process.ProcessId, process.Name
    except Exception:
        bad_assets.append(asset)
```

Also, trying to catch the right exception is recommended.